# Multiple passes render to separate textures

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures, render-to-texture

I am using the render to texture method for creating a multi shader program. And for various reasons. I need to first render a model to a texture with one shader program. Then render it again with a different shader program into a different texture. Then I have one final post processing shader that combines the results of the two. My problem is it seems that the second texture is overwriting the first texture. Is there a way to move textures? Or to render to a different texture without overwriting it. (Thanks for any help in advance!)

I have attached my code for reference:

```
// Basic rendering parameters
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();                   // Model-view matrix for the main object
var pMatrix = mat4.create();                    // Projection matrix

// Lighting control
var lightMatrix = mat4.create();                // Model-view matrix for the point light source
var lightPos = vec3.create();                   // Camera-space position of the light source
var lightPower = 5.0;                           // "Power" of the light source

// Common parameters for shading models
var diffuseColor = [0.2392, 0.5216, 0.7765];    // Diffuse color
var specularColor = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];            // Specular color
var ambientIntensity = 0.1;                     // Ambient

// Animation related variables
var rotY = 0.0;                                 // object rotation
var rotY_light = 0.0;                           // light position rotation

//Set the shader variables from pMat (projection matrix) and
//    from mMat which is the model and view transforms
function setUniforms(prog,pMat,mMat) {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.pMatrixUniform, false, pMat);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.mvMatrixUniform, false, mMat);

    var nMatrix = mat4.transpose(mat4.inverse(mMat));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.nMatrixUniform, false, nMatrix);


    gl.uniform3fv(prog.lightPosUniform, lightPos);
    gl.uniform1f(prog.lightPowerUniform, lightPower);
    gl.uniform3fv(prog.kdUniform, diffuseColor);
    gl.uniform3fv(prog.ksUniform, specularColor);
    gl.uniform1f(prog.ambientUniform, ambientIntensity);
}


function setLightPosition()
{
    mat4.identity(lightMatrix);
    mat4.translate(lightMatrix, [0.0, -1.0, -7.0]);
    mat4.rotateX(lightMatrix, 0.3);
    mat4.rotateY(lightMatrix, rotY_light);

    lightPos.set([0.0, 2.5, 3.0]);
    mat4.multiplyVec3(lightMatrix, lightPos); 
}

var draw_edge = true;
var draw_light = false;


//will need to be updated to allow for multiple meshes
//Does the toon rendering of the scene to a texture so that we can post process on it
function renderSceneToTexture(shaderProg,mesh,color,depth,mMat,width,height)
{
    var textOuput = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,textOuput);
    var format; var internalFormat;
    if(color)
    {
        internalFormat= gl.RGBA;
        format = gl.RGBA;
    }
    else
    {
        internalFormat= gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA;
        format = gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA;
    }
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,internalFormat,width,height,0,format,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,null);

    //set out of bounds accesses to clamp and set sub pixel accesses to lerp
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,fb);

    //set frame buffer to first attacthment position
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D,textOuput,0);


    var depthBuffer;
    if(depth)
    {
        depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
        gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
        gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
        gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, 
                                   gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    }

    var pMat = mat4.create(); 
    mat4.perspective(35, width/height, 0.1, 1000.0, pMat);
 
 
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Clear the attachment(s).
    gl.clearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);   // clear to black
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    gl.useProgram(shaderProg);
    setUniforms(shaderProg,pMat,mMat);
  

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProg.vertexPositionAttribute, mesh.vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.normalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProg.vertexNormalAttribute, mesh.normalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.indexBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, mesh.indexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    if ( draw_light ) {
        gl.useProgram(lightProgram);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(lightProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMat);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lightPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, Float32Array.from(lightPos), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(lightProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    }

    //should I unbind texture?
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.deleteFramebuffer(fb);
     // render to the canvas
    //gl.useProgram(null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
    return textOuput;
}

//mat4.copy was giving me errors, so I just copied the source code in here lol
function copy(out, a)
{
    out[0] = a[0];
  out[1] = a[1];
  out[2] = a[2];
  out[3] = a[3];
  out[4] = a[4];
  out[5] = a[5];
  out[6] = a[6];
  out[7] = a[7];
  out[8] = a[8];
  out[9] = a[9];
  out[10] = a[10];
  out[11] = a[11];
  out[12] = a[12];
  out[13] = a[13];
  out[14] = a[14];
  out[15] = a[15];
}

//Set the shader variables from pMat (projection matrix) and
//    from mMat which is the model and view transforms
function setPostprocessingUniforms(prog,texture,normalTexture, width, height) {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0); //Do I need this?
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture); //and this?
    gl.uniform1i(prog.uTextureUniform, texture);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1); //Do I need this?
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, normalTexture); //and this?
    gl.uniform1i(prog.normImageTextureUniform, normalTexture);

    gl.uniform2fv(prog.uTextureSizeUniform, [width,height]);
    gl.uniform2fv(prog.uResolutionUniform, [width,height]);
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function drawScene() {

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, -1.0, -7.0]);
    mat4.rotateX(mvMatrix, 0.3);
    mat4.rotateY(mvMatrix, rotY);
    mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, currentTransform);
    var cpy = mat4.create();
    copy(cpy,mvMatrix);

    setLightPosition();
    //consumes cpy matrix
    //actual shader but writes to a texture
    var normalsAsTexture =  renderSceneToTexture(normalPassProgram,currentMesh,true,true,mvMatrix,gl.viewportWidth,gl.viewportHeight);
    var sceneAsTexture =  renderSceneToTexture(currentProgram,currentMesh,true,true,cpy,gl.viewportWidth,gl.viewportHeight);



    // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
    setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        //screen is just 2 triangles, so we will post process on that
    var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

    //bug is probably here and in set rectangle
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      0.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      0.0,  1.0,
      1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);




    //Post-process shader
    gl.useProgram(postProcessProgram);
    setPostprocessingUniforms(postProcessProgram,sceneAsTexture,normalsAsTexture, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    //gl.activeTexture(texture);


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      postProcessProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      postProcessProgram.texturePositionAttribute, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);


    // Draw the rectangle.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 6;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);

    /*
    setUniforms(postProcessProgram,pMatrix,mvMatrix);  

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, currentMesh.vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(postProcessProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, currentMesh.vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, currentMesh.normalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(postProcessProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, currentMesh.normalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentMesh.indexBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, currentMesh.indexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    */


    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
    gl.deleteTexture(sceneAsTexture);
    gl.deleteTexture(normalsAsTexture);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking for errors in [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console)?

### LUMINANCE_ALPHA is not guaranteed to be renderable

Being able to render to `gl.LUMINANCE_ALPHA` is not a format that is guaranteed to work. In WebGL 1 only `gl.RGBA/gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` is guaranteed to work. All other format/type combos are not. You can check by calling

```
const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
const canRender = status === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE;
```

Though given rendering to `LUMINANCE_ALPHA` is commonly not supported you might want to just avoid it. It's not supported on MacOS for sure.

### gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight do not exist

`gl.viewportWidth` and `gl.viewportHeight` are not a thing, they don't exist. They are not part of any spec. One of the first WebGL tutorials (no longer on the net) made those up and confused thousands of devs.

### the code never turns on buffers on attributes

You need to call `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` for each attribute that you
want get its values from a buffer. Or to put it another way, for each call to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` you also need to call `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`

### sampler uniforms are set to texture units not textures

This code

```
 gl.uniform1i(prog.uTextureUniform, texture);
```

makes no sense. Textures are bound to an array of texture units. You select the unit with `gl.activeTexture` and then bind the texture to that unit with `gl.bindTexture`. You then tell the shader which unit you assigned the texture with `gl.uniform1i`.  See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html)

```
const unit = 6;  // pick a unit

// bind some texture to that unit
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);

// tell the shader to look at that unit for the texture
gl.uniform1i(someSamplerLocation, unit);
```

---

Other comments

- it's pretty much never important to unbind a texture
- it's not common to create and delete resources while rendering

  creating and deleting textures and framebuffers is slow. It would be more common
  to create them at init time and just use them at render time.
- Try to post a runnable [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in the future
- not sure what math library you're using but it looks kind of like gl-matrix? Many calls to `mat4.xxx` do not match the current API for [gl-matrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html) but without the source of your matrix library it's hard to tell if those calls are correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond and slug through my beginner code. I do manually define gl.viewportWidth and gl.viewportHeight, so that isn't a problem. I will try your suggestions, if they work then I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't manually define `gl.viewportWidth` and `gl.viewportHeight`. They are only confusing. If you want the size of the canvas use `gl.canvas.width` and `gl.canvas.height` or `gl.drawingbufferWidth` and `gl.drawingbufferHeight`. Those are defined. No reason to make more work for yourself and continue the confusion. I don't care if you mark my answer. I rather care that you ask a better question. The truth is I should have just voted to close as you have not provided enough code to reproduce the issue and therefore your question is off topic. There were obvious issue though so I answered

Comment: Yep, I just didn't fully understand texture units and `gl.uniform1i(someSamplerLocation, unit);` So, thank you for your help. People like you help make my understanding of things so much better! So thank you again!

Comment: You might find [this](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint) helpful in finding errors